# Array confusion in php in loop (getting syntax error of unexpected '[') + Confusion regarding displaying CSV file using php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am new to programming and having trouble using arrays in php. Can someone explain what am I doing wrong here? I am getting an error saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/jharvard/vhosts/pset7/includes/functions.php on line 263

```
// declare arrays and counter to be returned
$i = 0;
$dates = array();
$prices = array();

// loops over the file and stores the values
while (($data = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) 
{
    $dates[$i] = data[0];
    $prices[$i] = data[1];
    $prices[$i] = number_format($price[$i], 2);  
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a php version under 5.4 so you can't use this syntax! see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: What's you php version? You can use short array syntax only in and after php 5.4.

Comment: I've just assumed the obvious answer to these questions. If he comes back and says a recent version, I'll reopen.

Comment: It is 5.5.3. It's more than 5.4, right?

Comment: Yes it is! So we can call @Barmar to reopen it :D And you could maybe past a little bit more code and write the exact error message with line

Comment: Done. What's on line 263?

Comment: This is on line 263: $dates[$i] = data[0];

Comment: You're missing the `$` before `data` on those two lines.

Comment: So this question should be closed because it's just due to a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems $ sign was missing on this two lines

```
$dates[$i] = data[0];
$prices[$i] = data[1];
```

It should be

```
$dates[$i] = $data[0];
$prices[$i] = $data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file_get_contents($csvfile);
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file));
$cnt=count($data);

for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
@$data[$i][0]  //1st column of csv //
@$data[$i][1] //2nd column
```